# When would you use "man" instead of personal pronouns?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

I just learned that the word "man" can mean "you", among other things. When would you use "man" instead of du, ihr, and Sie? I can see it being used as an indefinite pronoun, e.g. "One must always be alert", but I have a hard time distinguishing when to use it in place of personal pronouns. Especially when the subject is "you" (sg./pl.) or "they".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When would you use "man" instead of du, ihr, and Sie?

"*Man*" is used to express a "general rule" where the word "*you*" in the English sentence actually means: "everyone" or "anyone"

Example:

> In this supermarket **you** can buy apples.
>
> In diesem Supermarkt kann **man** Äpfel kaufen.

The "*you*" in the English sentence does not mean: **You** can buy apples but other persons can't. It means: **Everyone** can buy apples.

"*Man*" is also used to express that is does not matter (or it is not known) who has done something when the word "*they*" would be used in English. The word "*man*" can often be used to express a sentence in active form instead of using the passive.

Example:

> **They** told him that the apples were sold out. (active)
>
> He was told that ... (passive)
>
> **Man** hat ihm gesagt, dass ... (active)
>
> Ihm wurde gesagt, dass ... (passive, just for completeness)

Comment: This makes sense, as it builds on its use as an indefinite pronoun. Thanks.

Comment: I think a clearer way to think about it is that *man* means 'one' (indefinite pronoun), but in English 'you' is sometimes used to mean 'one'. In those cases *man* is the right translation for 'you', and 'you' may often be a more idiomatic translation for *man*.

Comment: The question title is a good example, actually - "when would *you* use man" would likely be phrased using *man* in German.

Comment: As stated, man is closest to "one".